# x509 openssl in C

Tags: c++, vb.net, ssl

I successfully managed to dynamically link OpenSSL library into my C++ code :) after some struggle.
Now I need to perform the same task I can do in VB .NET, like this:

' encrypt a string using a X509 certificate
    Dim rsaCSP As RSACryptoServiceProvider = New RSACryptoServiceProvider

```
Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(My.Resources.SanitelCF)
rsaCSP = cert.PublicKey.Key
Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inStringa.Trim)
Dim bytout As Byte() = rsaCSP.Encrypt(byt, False)
Return Convert.ToBase64String(bytout)
```

...and actually would just like to know which functions I should use/call. I am not much into security, just did some AES in the past: now we have this requirement by the italian government, and I would like to add that to my Libraries.

I've been searching for this to quite some extent, but only found other stuff, such as DES or Blowfish with OpenSSL.

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it working!

This is my "rough" code for performing the requested action using OpenSSL C library with dynamic link from a Windows DLL (unamanaged):

This is what I wanted:

openssl.exe rsautl -encrypt -in input.txt -out output.txt -inkey SanitelCF.cer -certin -pkcs

openssl.exe base64 -base64 -e -in output.txt -out output.b64

```
        //  openssl.exe rsautl -encrypt -in input.txt -out output.txt -inkey SanitelCF.cer -certin -pkcs
        //  openssl.exe base64 -base64 -e -in output.txt -out output.b64

                    //http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822
                    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194650/sign-a-file-with-openssl-in-php-and-verify-in-c
                    //http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/use-openssl-function-in-own-application-td47685.html
                    //https://shanetully.com/2012/06/openssl-rsa-aes-and-c/
                    //http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-7.1/openssl/apps/rsautl.c?txt

    #define RSA_SIGN    1
    #define RSA_VERIFY  2
    #define RSA_ENCRYPT     3
    #define RSA_DECRYPT     4

    #define KEY_PRIVKEY 1
    #define KEY_PUBKEY  2
    #define KEY_CERT    3

    #define FORMAT_UNDEF    0
    #define FORMAT_ASN1     1
    #define FORMAT_TEXT     2
    #define FORMAT_PEM      3
    #define FORMAT_NETSCAPE 4
    #define FORMAT_PKCS12   5
    #define FORMAT_SMIME    6

    int app_RAND_load_file(const char *file, BIO *bio_e, int dont_warn);
    X509 *load_cert(BIO *err, char *file, int format);

    //  BIO *in = NULL, *out = NULL;
    //  char *infile = "rsain.txt", *outfile = "rsaout.txt";
    //  char *keyfile = "sanitelCF.cer";
        char rsa_mode = RSA_VERIFY, key_type = KEY_PRIVKEY;
        int keyform = FORMAT_PEM;
        char need_priv = 0, badarg = 0, rev = 0;
    //  char hexdump = 0, asn1parse = 0;
        X509 *x;
        EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
        RSA *rsa = NULL;
        unsigned char *rsa_in = NULL, *rsa_out = NULL, pad;
        int rsa_inlen, rsa_outlen = 0;
        int keysize;
        BIO *bio_err=NULL;

                    HINSTANCE hi=LoadLibrary("libeay32.dll");
                    typedef void (FAR *CRYPTO_free_PROC)(void *);
                    typedef void (FAR *BIO_free_all_PROC)(BIO *);
                    typedef int (FAR *BIO_free_PROC)(BIO *);
                    typedef void (FAR *RSA_free_PROC)(RSA *);
                    typedef int (FAR *RSA_public_encrypt_PROC)(int,const BYTE *,BYTE *,RSA *,int);
                    typedef int (FAR *BIO_read_PROC)(BIO *,void *,int);
                    typedef void * (FAR *CRYPTO_malloc_PROC)(int,const char *,int);
                    typedef int (FAR *RSA_size_PROC)(const RSA *);
                    typedef BIO * (FAR *BIO_new_file_PROC)(const char *,const char *);
                    typedef void (FAR *EVP_PKEY_free_PROC)(EVP_PKEY *);
                    typedef struct rsa_st * (FAR *EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA_PROC)(EVP_PKEY *);
                    typedef int (FAR *BIO_printf_PROC)(BIO *bio, const char *format, ...);
                    typedef EVP_PKEY * (FAR *X509_get_pubkey_PROC)(X509 *);
                    typedef long (FAR *BIO_ctrl_PROC)(BIO *,int,long,void *);
                    typedef BIO * (FAR *BIO_new_PROC)(BIO_METHOD *);
                    typedef BIO_METHOD * (FAR *BIO_s_file_PROC)(void);
                    typedef void (FAR *X509_free_PROC)(X509 *);
                    typedef BIO * (FAR *BIO_new_fp_PROC)(FILE *,int);



                    RSA_public_encrypt_PROC myRSA_public_encrypt;
                    CRYPTO_free_PROC myCRYPTO_free;
                    BIO_free_all_PROC myBIO_free_all;
                    BIO_free_PROC myBIO_free;
                    RSA_free_PROC myRSA_free;
                    BIO_read_PROC myBIO_read;
                    CRYPTO_malloc_PROC myCRYPTO_malloc;
                    RSA_size_PROC myRSA_size;
                    BIO_new_file_PROC myBIO_new_file;
                    EVP_PKEY_free_PROC myEVP_PKEY_free;
                    EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA_PROC myEVP_PKEY_get1_RSA;
                    BIO_printf_PROC myBIO_printf;
                    X509_get_pubkey_PROC myX509_get_pubkey;
                    BIO_ctrl_PROC myBIO_ctrl;
                    BIO_new_PROC myBIO_new;
                    BIO_s_file_PROC myBIO_s_file;
                    X509_free_PROC myX509_free;
                    BIO_new_fp_PROC myBIO_new_fp;

                    if(myRSA_public_encrypt=(RSA_public_encrypt_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"RSA_public_encrypt")) {

                        myCRYPTO_free=(CRYPTO_free_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"CRYPTO_free");
                        myBIO_free_all=(BIO_free_all_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_free_all");
                        myBIO_free=(BIO_free_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_free");
                        myRSA_free=(RSA_free_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"RSA_free");
                        myBIO_read=(BIO_read_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_read");
                        myCRYPTO_malloc=(CRYPTO_malloc_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"CRYPTO_malloc");
                        myRSA_size=(RSA_size_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"RSA_size");
                        myBIO_new_file=(BIO_new_file_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_new_file");
                        myEVP_PKEY_free=(EVP_PKEY_free_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"EVP_PKEY_free");
                        myEVP_PKEY_get1_RSA=(EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA");
                        myBIO_printf=(BIO_printf_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_printf");
                        myX509_get_pubkey=(X509_get_pubkey_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"X509_get_pubkey");
                        myBIO_ctrl=(BIO_ctrl_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_ctrl");
                        myBIO_new=(BIO_new_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_new");
                        myBIO_s_file=(BIO_s_file_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_s_file");
                        myX509_free=(X509_free_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"X509_free");
                        myBIO_new_fp=(BIO_new_fp_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"BIO_new_fp");


                        ASSERT(0);
    //                  FILE *z=fopen("picio.txt","w+");
    //                  bio_err = myBIO_new_fp(stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);    // dà sempre un'eccezione strana in openssl... evito!

                        pad = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING; // fisso DOVREBBE essere giusto per noi!

                        app_RAND_load_file(NULL,bio_err,0);
                        x = load_cert(bio_err,myBuf2,keyform);
                        if(x) {
                            if(d) {
                                X509_NAME *xs;
                                typedef X509_NAME * (FAR *X509_get_issuer_name_PROC)(X509 *);
                                X509_get_issuer_name_PROC myX509_get_issuer_name;
                                myX509_get_issuer_name=(X509_get_issuer_name_PROC)GetProcAddress(hi,"X509_get_issuer_name");
                                xs=myX509_get_issuer_name(x);
                                MessageBox(NULL,"Certificate Dump (TODO)","Information",MB_OK);
    //                          MessageBox(NULL,xs->bytes,"Information",MB_OK);     non compila, frocio
                                }

                            pkey = myX509_get_pubkey(x);
                            myX509_free(x);
                            }

                        if(!pkey) {
                            MessageBox(NULL,"GetRSA: Error loading key or CERT","Error",MB_OK);
    //                      myBIO_printf(bio_err, "Error loading key\n");
    //                      return 1;
                            goto end;
                            }

                        rsa = myEVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
                        myEVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

                        if(!rsa) {
                            MessageBox(NULL,"GetRSA: Error getting RSA key","Error",MB_OK);
    //                      myBIO_printf(bio_err, "Error getting RSA key\n");
    //                      ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
                            goto end;
                            }


    //                  if(!(in = myBIO_new_file(infile, "rb"))) {      // PER PROVA! poi, stringhe
    //                      myBIO_printf(bio_err, "Error Reading Input File\n");
    //                      ERR_print_errors(bio_err);  
    //                      goto end;
    //                      }

    //                  if(!(out = myBIO_new_file(outfile, "wb"))) {
    //                      myBIO_printf(bio_err, "Error Reading Output File\n");
    //                      ERR_print_errors(bio_err);  
    //                      goto end;
    //                      }


                        keysize = myRSA_size(rsa);

                        rsa_in = (BYTE *)myCRYPTO_malloc(keysize*2,__FILE__,__LINE__);          // mappa da OPENSSL_malloc; v. crypto.h
                        rsa_out = (BYTE *)myCRYPTO_malloc(keysize,__FILE__,__LINE__);

                        /* Read the input data */
                        rsa_inlen=min(_tcslen(myBuf),keysize*2);
                        memcpy(rsa_in,myBuf,rsa_inlen);
    //                  rsa_inlen = myBIO_read(in, rsa_in, keysize*2);
    //                  if(rsa_inlen <= 0) {
    //                      myBIO_printf(bio_err, "Error reading input Data\n");
    //                      exit(1);
    //                      }
                        if(rev) {       // non dovrebbe interessarci a noi
                            int i;
                            unsigned char ctmp;
                            for(i=0; i<rsa_inlen/2; i++) {
                                ctmp = rsa_in[i];
                                rsa_in[i] = rsa_in[rsa_inlen-1-i];
                                rsa_in[rsa_inlen-1-i] = ctmp;
                                }
                            }

                        rsa_outlen = myRSA_public_encrypt(rsa_inlen,rsa_in,rsa_out,rsa,pad);

                        if(rsa_outlen <= 0) {
    //                      BIO_printf(bio_err, "RSA operation error\n");
    //                      ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
    //                      goto end;
                            }

    //                  int ret = 0;
    //                  myBIO_dump(out,(char *)rsa_out,rsa_outlen);
    //                  myBIO_write(out,rsa_out,rsa_outlen);
                        Base64encode(szBuf,(const char *)rsa_out,rsa_outlen);
    //                  memcpy(szBuf,rsa_out,rsa_outlen);
    //                  szBuf[rsa_outlen]=0;

    end:
                        myRSA_free(rsa);
    //                  myBIO_free(in);
    //                  myBIO_free_all(out);
                        if(rsa_in) 
                            myCRYPTO_free(rsa_in);          //OPENSSL_free(rsa_in);     questa caga il cazzo con "3 parametri"... boh
                        if(rsa_out) 
                            myCRYPTO_free(rsa_out);         //mappa su CRYPTO_free(rsa_out);



                        FreeLibrary(hi);
```

Now working and improving the above. References used are listed as notes :)